# Compile vs Compiles

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder, should I say,

"Will the following program compile?"

Or

"Will the following program compiles?"

Is the verb "compile" treated differently than other verbs?

Comment: No, what makes you think it would? With every other verb you should not put that **s** there, since you need an infinitive.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that "will X does something" is correct. I suggest you have a look ate [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Will* is a [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modals.pdf), and
all modal auxiliary verbs [must be followed by an infinitive verb form](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) (**without** *to*).

Since *compile* is an infinitive form, while *compiles* is not, the second example is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

I compile.

You compile.

He/She/It compiles.

We compile.

They compile.

Will this program compile?

Yes, this program compiles.

Comment: Does "this program" equivalent to "it"? Shouldn't I treat it the same thus saying "Will this program compiles?"

Comment: No, I guess you are treating all other verbs wrong as well then. It is "Will he **walk**", not "Will he walks".

Answer (score 0):

> Does the verb "compile" treated differently than other verbs?

No.